# How to display data from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have some issues displaying the data from my multidimensional array. Is a 3 array combined in 1.

I have combined the arrays like this:

```
$sums = array_merge(array($titlu), array($dimensiune), array($datalink));
```

Now, the code that I am using to display the array, is:

```
for($r=0;$r<count($sums);$r++)
{
    for($c=0;$c<count($sums[$r]);$c++)
    {
        echo $sums[$r][$c]."<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
```

But this displays like:

```
$sums[0][0]
$sums[1][0]
$sums[2][0]
$sums[0][1]
$sums[1][1]
$sums[2][1]
and so on...
```

Above example with or without the new line, outputs every array one at a time.

What I need to show is to combine the data from the arrays like position 0 from array 0 with position 0 from array 1 and position 0 from array 3, like this:

```
$sums[0][0] ... $sums[1][0] ... $sums[2][0]
$sums[0][1] ... $sums[1][1] ... $sums[2][1]
and so on...
```

So everytime the first value is fixed, like 0, 1 and 2... and the other one can go from 1 to X, those being the entries i want to put in my database

How can I achieve this? 
Thank you guys.

Comment: You have `<br />` after every `$sums[$r][$c]`, but you don't want it. So why not just remove this and move it to the **correct** please?

Comment: @Dekel you mean *place

Comment: yes yes :) place :) haha sorry

Comment: Still doesn't do what I want... this thing outputs me every array one element at a time. I want to combine the output from all 3 arrays. Like position 0 from every array, position 1 from every array and so on

Comment: I don't see any change to your question.

Comment: Your code prints `$sums[0][0] $sums[0][1] $sums[0][2] $sums[1][0] $sums[1][1] $sums[1][2]`, not the order you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print all the `$sums[$r][0]` elements, then all the `$sums[$r][1]` elements, and so on, you need to rearrange the loops. You have to iterate over column numbers in the outer loop, then over rows in inner loop.

```
$colcount = count($sums[0]);
for ($c = 0; $c < $colcount; $c++) {
    foreach ($sums as $row) {
        echo $row[$c] . " ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you very much, exactly what I wanted.